# Samba 4.5.1 Windows 2012R2 LDAP

Tags: linux, windows, active-directory, ldap, samba

The Question is more or less, a "is it possible"-Question and if yes, some hints how to accomplish it would be nice.

My plan is as follows:

I want to setup Samba 4.5.1 on Centos/Debian as PDC. Also I want it to be clustered (=have a failover server). I have two completely same DELL Server. The users which are created there (LDAP users?) should be able to login on a NextloudServer and on other services like Anyconnect. Also we have a Windows2012R2 Server which has currently is own Domain. I want him to join the Samba Domain. So i don't have windows.local and unix.local - these Samba Users should also be able to login on the windows machine.

This would be very nice, also a fileserver should join the LDAP (?) users and I only have to care about one user profile. At the moment I have a user account for every server local on every single machine. So Nextcloud, Anyconnect, Fileserver & Windows-server are 4 seperate accounts with the same username/password. This is not the smartest and easiest way to manage users.

What I have done --> Installed Samba 4.5.1 from source on Virtual machine running Centos7. Created a test domain test.local and created User A with `samba-tool user create USERA` . Read the man page of samba-tool ;-)

I hope this shouldn't be posted in UNIX & Linux Forum. Any hints, tips and "How To"-links are welcome. Your opinion also.

And I don't want to have a Windows Server as PDC, because I want to concentrate and focus my knowledge on Linux enviroment and not on "Windows GUI clicking" (which is also nice but not my plan ;-) )

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

DC do not needs to be clustered. It's fail-safe by design.

Windows DC can't be joined to another domain.

> And I also don't want to have a Windows Server as PDC. Because I want
>   to concentrate on Linux enviroment and not Windows GUI clicking.

Forget the notion of "PDC" is out of date many years ago. Also you should understand that Samba implements Active Directory DC not in full. And yet there PowerShell - you can install Windows DC without any "GUI clicking"... 
absolutely without GUI.

Active Directory is not only LDAP!

And before doing anything try read about Active Directory:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashwinexchange/2012/12/18/understanding-active-directory-for-beginners-part-1/
https://zappytech.wordpress.com/2013/03/19/active-directory-basics/

or view the a training video:

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=+Introduction+to+Active+Directory

Most of your questions will be gone.

Comment: I will watch the links, maybe I expressed myself wrong - i dont want the Windowsserver become a Domain Controller, I just want him to join the domain as a member - I read that it should be possible with the 4.5.1 but not stable.